# Fitting data without an equation

Tags: plotting

Let's say I have some data generated by anything. For practical sake, let's say I was able to generate a sequence of numbers through a recursion and I listed them out through a table of numbers.

```
F[1] = 1;
F[n_] := 3*F[n - 1]
H = Table[F[n], {n, 1, 10}]
```

Now I set the table of values to a variable 'w'

```
ListPlot[H]
```

Here I am plotting the data.

What I want to do now is to "fit" a curve that connects all those points. I just want to see the fitted curve on the plot together the data points. I don't even need (or want to) see the equation that best fits the data.

I tried using NonlinearModel and Fit, neither works well for me. The recursion is just an example. I could of course product new data from something else

Comment: The simplest fit is linear interpolation between data points. And that is done by using the following magical incantation: `ListPlot[H, Joined -> True]`. Do you want anything fancier that this? If so, could you describe it in more detail?

Comment: add the option Joined->True and possibly PlotMarkers->Automatic to ListPlot

Comment: Do you have information on what this plot is to be used for, i.e. what inferences are to be drawn from it

Comment: Nope, none at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to see the plot:

```
ListPlot[H, Mesh -> Full, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What does the 'order' do?

Comment: @jak It smooths out the curve. Try with values  from 0 to 3

Comment: So I am guessing the higher the value, the better?

Comment: @jak why don't you position your cursor on that keyword and press F1? You'll get your answer right away...

Comment: It's interesting, when I make an recursion. If I set the InterpolationOrder greater than 2, my recurison starts back at $-1$ instead of 0

Answer (score 3):

My best guess as to what you really want is [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html):

```
F[1] = 1;
F[n_] := 3*F[n - 1]
H = Table[F[n], {n, 1, 10}];

f = Interpolation[H]
```

> `InterpolatingFunction[{{1,10}},<>]`

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image: interpolation]

Comment: I am getting "InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.000204286} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>"

Comment: @jak An `InterpolatingFunction` only matches the data its given and won't provide an accurate fit/prediction at values outside of the limits of the data. Here those limits are 1 and 10 as `H` is a list of 10 numbers (not x-y pairs) so Mma assigns an x-coord of 1,2,3... to each y value. When you try plot beyond the limits (as at $x\simeq0$ above) Mma warns that you're working outside of the 'safe' domain of `f` and that the results at these points may not be trustworthy. Often plots of an `InterpolationFunction` far from its 'safe' domain can look very strange compared to the data its based on

Answer (score 0):

You just need to plot the the power function:

```
Show[Plot[3^(n - 1), {n, 1, 10}], ListPlot[H]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: My understanding was that the data aren't necessarily given by a known function...

Comment: @Jens, that's exactly what I mean. I just made up this example.