# Fitting a curve provided from a table

Tags: plotting

Code is as follows.

```
aSet1 = {0.05447969195001433`, {1.62844, 1.79419}};
aSet2 = {0.05448351166864853`, {1.63506, 1.78729}};
aSet3 = {0.054488286316941295`, {1.64428, 1.77771}};
aSet4 = {0.05449306096523404`, {1.65507, 1.76657}};
aSet5 = {0.05449783561352681`, {1.66863, 1.75266}};
aSet6 = {0.054502610261819566`, {1.68992, 1.73102}};
aSet7 = {0.05450356519147811`, {1.69803, 1.72284}};
aSet8 = {0.052521131220325465`, {1.03786, 2.5299}};
aSet9 = {0.042971834634811745`, {0.353918, 3.94334}};
aSet10 = {0.033422538049298026`, {0.102792, 4.96211}};
aSet11 = {0.023873241463784306`, {5.87487, 5.87487}};
aSet12 = {0.014323944878270583`, {6.74069, 6.74069}};
aSet13 = {0.00954929658551372`, {7.16397, 7.16397}};

Tck400 = {aSet1, aSet2, aSet3, aSet4, aSet5, aSet6, aSet7, aSet8, 
aSet9, aSet10, aSet11, aSet12, aSet13};

c400 = ListPlot[{Table[{Tck400[[ii, 2, 2]], Tck400[[ii, 1]]}, {ii, 1, 
 Length[Tck400]}], Table[{Tck400[[ii, 2, 1]], Tck400[[ii, 1]]}, {ii, 1, 
 Length[Tck400]}]}, Frame -> True, RotateLabel -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All}]
```

With the following output (plot label wasn't included above):

[image]

I would like to ditch the points and plot a line or somehow fit a line to this data.
My only thought was changing the format of the data to simple (x,y) points.
Anything yall think would be nicer?
Thanks!

**Here is my solution based on rhermans solution**

```
Tck230 = {fSet1, fSet2, fSet3, fSet4, fSet5, fSet6, fSet7, fSet8, fSet9, fSet10, fSet11, fSet12, fSet13, fSet14, fSet15, fSet16};
line230 = SortBy[First]@Flatten[Distribute[Reverse@#, List] & /@ Tck230, 1];
```

[image]

**Here is my solution based on user1066 solution**

```
data230 = DeleteDuplicates[Catenate[{Table[{Tck230[[ii, 2, 2]], Tck230[[ii, 1]]}, {ii, 1, Length[Tck230]}], Table[{Tck230[[ii, 2, 1]], Tck230[[ii, 1]]}, {ii, 1, Length[Tck230]}]}]];
f230 = Interpolation@data230;
data230 // Plot[f230[x], {x, Min@(#[[All, 1]]), Max@(#[[All, 1]])}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7.5}, {0, 0.12}}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, Axes -> False] &
```

This was done for all curves, and the following was done for the overlay as done above:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `LinearModelFit`, `FindFit`, etc?

Comment: Duplicate? [(22293)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22293/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. `Joined -> True`

If you just want to join the points:

```
With[
 {
  data = SortBy[First]@
    Flatten[Distribute[Reverse@#, List] & /@ Tck400, 1]
  },
 Show[
  ListPlot[
   data
   , PlotStyle -> Blue
   , InterpolationOrder -> 2
   , Joined -> True
   , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
   , PlotRange -> All
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### 2. `FindFormula`

If you don't have a model, you can try to guess one using [`FindFormula`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html)

```
With[
 {
  data = SortBy[First]@
    Flatten[Distribute[Reverse@#, List] & /@ Tck400, 1]
  },
 Plot[
  Evaluate@FindFormula[data, x, SpecificityGoal -> "High"]
  , {x, Sequence @@ MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]}
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  , PlotRange -> {0, All}
  , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you good sir! :)

Comment: `ListLinePlot` is more canonical at this point and seems better supported, e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58996/121

Comment: Wasn't the only difference considered a bug? @Mr.Wizard

Comment: Well, yes, that case was a bug, but it supports my point that `ListLinePlot` received more development attention than `Joined -> True`.  I did not mean to detract from your answer which I voted for.

Comment: my code and subsequent plots have been greatly improved! Ill post my final product for anyone having a similar issue and would like to use @rhermans answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = Interpolation@data;
data // Plot[f[x], {x, Min@(#[[All, 1]]), Max@(#[[All, 1]])}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 7.5}, {0, 0.07}},
PlotStyle -> Red, 
Frame -> True, 
Axes -> False, 
FrameTicks -> {Subdivide[0, 7, 7], Subdivide[0.01, 0.06, 5]}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 data = DeleteDuplicates[Catenate[{Table[{Tck400[[ii, 2, 2]], Tck400[[ii, 1]]}, {ii, 1, 
   Length[Tck400]}], Table[{Tck400[[ii, 2, 1]], Tck400[[ii, 1]]}, {ii, 1, 
   Length[Tck400]}]}]];
```

**Edit**

In response to the OP comment the curves thus far are not smooth, thus providing ammunition for his advisor,  it might be better to fit the data to a specific model rather than use interpolation.   Nevertheless, increasing the interpolation order to 4 (from the default of 3) does seem to improve things.

```
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 4];
data // Plot[f[x], {x, Min@(#[[All, 1]]), Max@(#[[All, 1]])}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 7.5}, {0, 0.07}}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
FrameTicks -> {Subdivide[0, 7, 7], Subdivide[0.01, 0.06, 5]}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the interpolation function may be used to calculate y-values, provided that the x-values are within the interpolation range. (Useful for a 'standard curve' situation?)

```
f@3.5
```

> 0.0464684

```
f /@ Subdivide[Min@data[[All, 1]], 7, 10]
```

> {0.0334225, 0.0510192, 0.0543068, 0.0538228, 0.0507972, 0.0460776, 
>   0.0403554, 0.0337375, 0.0266037, 0.0191165, 0.0114045}

Comment: My advisor (@rhermans was gievn credit) just scolded me on the fact that my plots arent smooth haha so thank you for this!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  I am not getting many of those lately.  All advisors worship  at the alter of the smooth curve!

Comment: hehe of course mate! now I get to say even more people helped me online! I will edit the question with my update based on your work right now :)